Historically, when have the the real numbers been constructed via the "positive" (non-negative) reals first, and then usual real numbers second?
There has been something that has been bugging me for the longest time, at least since grad school.
In the teaching of mathematics, during the construction of the "usual" real numbers, why not use Dedekind Cuts containing only "positive" (nonzero) rational numbers instead of Dedekind Cuts of the usual kind? Perhaps by punting the details of the rest of the construction to the end of the discussion/book.  Or even by "hand-waving" the rest of the details away completely.
If I recall correctly, the greatest difficulty with the classical Dedekind construction of the real numbers (as a field) lies with the difficulty of proving that the multiplication of "two" traditional Dedekind cuts results in an operation that satisfies the axioms defining a field.  Because, of course, a traditional Dedekind Cut potentially contains both positive and negative rational numbers.  Similar difficulties arise via the use of Cauchy sequences in such constructions.
In modern notation, taking this approach would involve the construction of
$${\Huge{\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}}}$$
first and then applying the same trick that constructs ${\mathbb{Z}}$ from ${\mathbb{N}}$ to proceed to the full construction of
$${\Huge{\mathbb{R}}}$$ second.
Students, at that point in their education, have possibly (and even likely?) already seen the construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$!  Regardless, I do not understand why this is not a more common approach, represented in a common textbook.
Not only that, this approach would make historic sense.  Weren't the "positive" reals constructed first, before the "usual" real numbers were?
Now I sincerely doubt my essential question here has not been thought about or answered before, but after some digging around online for over an hour, I have not found much that addresses this question directly.  Thanks.
This brings to mind a few other ideas, potentially already present in mathematical pedagogy: "Dedekind vectors" (containing zero), "Dedekind complete ordered posifields", etc...
Note 1: This needs mild editing, but hopefully the question I pose here is clear.
Note 2: For clarification about what official question I want to ask, it all goes back to the title of my question, read alone.
That was not exactly the question in my mind when I was writing the body of the question, but that's where my thinking was heading as I wrote the question body. I say this because exposition/pedagogy often trails closely behind historical developments, and sometimes expository/pedagogical questions inspire novel mathematical ideas.

I'm not clear what we are trying to construct.  $\mathbb R^+$ is not a field and if we were attempting to construct an ordered field with the least upper bound property what were we trying to construct?  I'm not saying I disagree with you construction.  I'm just not sure what our requirements are.  A set with LUB prop? but with addition and mulitplication that distributes .... but where additive inverses don't exist?  Not sure how completely and well defined that is.

I'm a little confused in that I'm pretty sure I've seen exactly what you propose done in a couple real analysis texts. Is this question a [reference-request] without the tag, or am I misunderstanding something?

I understand the question as asking whether it's easier to construct the nonnegative reals as a complete metric space (with the structure of a monoid) from the nonnegative rationals, and then formally inverting the nonzero elements to obtain $\mathbb R$. "Easier" in the sense that there are less difficulties in proving that addition of two cuts is well-defined.

Have a look at Edmund Landau's Book Grundlagen der Analysis from 1930. An english Version you may find here:  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Landau.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwinooqj4cCFAxXnwAIHHZsWBuM4FBAWegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1tV3oa86PDde5AZLiL-CYw

@fleablood To answer your question: what is now known as a Semifield in the second sense mention in that article.  I just searched for that, I suspected there was already such a thing, but didn't look up the name.

@manthanomen You're essentially correct in one sense: in my question, that's the crucial point: the ease of construction as you suggest.  Well, plus or minus some ordering of the construction of a "complete metric space" after the construction of the order-algebraic structure of the "positive" real numbers, which then can be proved to be complete in the Cauchy sense.

The usual constructions of $\mathbb R$ via Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences are all based on the rationals.  Now $\mathbb Q$ has the advantage over $\mathbb Q^+$ in that $\mathbb Q$ is a field, which would explain the order you are wondering about.
Historically speaking, the positive real numbers certainly came earlier.  They were introduced already by Simon Stevin many decades before the work of Leibniz and Newton.  Stevin popularized the approach of representing each number (rational or not) by an unending decimal.  This is of course also a rigorous approach to the reals.  Negative numbers were accepted as legitimate "numbers" in the number system only in the 19th century.

Nice!  Thanks.  Any other answers, from anyone else?
